# Displaying an editText

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have two activities. In the first one I'm requesting users to enter their name and i want to pass the name in my second activity.
My codes in the first activity are:

```
name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
String str = name.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("str", str);
```

And my codes in the second activity are:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getExtras().getString("str");
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
t.setText(name);
```

The problem is that nothing is displayed on my second activity.

Comment: did you start the second activity with that Intent or with other?

Comment: @Victoria Are you sure that R.id.textResult is correct id ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the `startActivity()` anywhere... so I put how your code should like and you implement it .

```
name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
String str = name.getText().toString();

Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("str", str);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `ResultActivity` you do this :

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
 if(b!=null){
    String name =(String) b.get("str");
    t.setText(name);
}
```

Ok, so you can use SharedPreferences to do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); 
editor.putString("NamePlayer", name); //Here you save the text of your edittext 
editor.commit();
```

Then on your result activity do this :

```
SharedPreferencessharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext)); 
String  name =sharedPreferences.getString("NamePlayer", "NoName"));
```

Comment: But i have other activities between my WelcomeActivity and my ResultActivity. I can't put start activity in the Welcome activity, the app crashes. The idea is to get the user's name at the begining of the app and to display his name with his result at the end of the game.

Comment: Ive edited my answer, sorry Im on phone so i cant make it looks good on a few minutes i'll edit it but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the second Activity use the following code, then your App will run perfectly:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("str");
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    t.setText(name);
```

Comment: But i have other activities between my WelcomeActivity and my ResultActivity. I can't put start activity in the Welcome activity, the app crashes. The idea is to get the user's name at the begining of the app and to display his name with his result at the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity after putting your Extra in your Intent, you have to start the second activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("str", str);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

I simulated your code and it works just fine.

Comment: But i have other activities between my WelcomeActivity and my ResultActivity. I can't put start activity in the Welcome activity, the app crashes. The idea is to get the user's name at the begining of the app and to display his name with his result at the end of the game.

Comment: Then you have to carry the value throughout all activities. PutExtra for every intent between the activities before invoking startActivityForResult